# Translate C# SOAP Post Request to PHP SOAP Post Request

Tags: c#, php, soap

The C# code looks like this:

```
private static string SendSoapRequest(string request, string destinationUrl)
    {
        string soapRequest = String.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"    encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                                           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
                                           "soap:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">" +
                                           "<soap:Body>{0}</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", request);

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapRequest);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/soap+xml";
        req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // enable cookies
        req.Referer = "localhost";
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream reqst = req.GetRequestStream(); // add form data to request stream
        reqst.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqst.Flush();
        reqst.Close();

        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        if (responseStream != null)
        {   
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return response;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

And my effort so far, among many other variations, in PHP wihtout success:

```
public static function sendSoapCurl($samlMessage, $destination, $action) {

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($samlMessage),
    );

    if (isset($action)) {
        $headers[] = "SOAPAction: $action";
    }

    // $samlMessage = utf8_encode($samlMessage);

    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $destination);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $samlMessage); // the SOAP request

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // get soap response
    $soapresponsexml = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($httpCode != 200) {
        print_r("Status code: ".$httpCode."\n");
        print_r($soapresponsexml);exit();
    }

    if ($soapresponsexml === null || $soapresponsexml === "") {
        throw new \Exception('Empty SOAP response, check peer certificate.');
    }

    try {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom = OneLogin_Saml2_Utils::loadXML($dom, $soapresponsexml);
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Not a SOAP response.', 0, $e);
    }
    $soapfault = self::getSOAPFault($dom);
    if (isset($soapfault)) {
        throw new \Exception($soapfault);
    }
}
```

The C# code works, but I can't get it to work in PHP. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* is not working? Please share your research effort. Please provide some more explanations of your code, what you are trying to do and what issue you are experiencing. It is hard to find an error in dozens or even hundreds lines of code. Please see also [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, was interested in a pure translation from C# to PHP. It turns out the piece I was missing was utf8 encoding the SOAP request, which solved the problem - utf8_encode($soapRequest).

Answer (score 0):

In the translation I was missing the utf8 encoding part. The addition of the line below solved my problem and the request now works:

```
$soapUtf8Request = utf8_encode($samlMessage);
```